# Sampled texture from bitmap font produces blue glow

Tags: directx11, hlsl, fonts

I'm creating a texture is DirectX 11 from bitmap fonts. I realize that I can use DXTK, but this is an exercise for me, not in learning another library. My sample code looks like this.

```
// Object Declarations
Texture2D g_MeshTexture;            // Color texture for mesh

SamplerState MeshTextureSampler
{
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
};

float4 PS(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_TARGET
{
    return g_MeshTexture.Sample(MeshTextureSampler, input.uv);
}
```

The texture of the rendered font produces strange blue artifacts where the text should have alpha values but instead appear as blue.

[image: Font test]

I did try gamma color correction with the code

```
float4 PS(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_TARGET
{
    float4 sRGBA = g_MeshTexture.Sample(MeshTextureSampler, input.uv);
    float3 sRGB = float3(sRGBA.x, sRGBA.y, sRGBA.z);
    float3 gRGB = pow(sRGB, 1/2.2);

    return float4(gRGB.x, gRGB.y, gRGB.z, sRGBA.w);
}
```

However this did not provide results any different from what the image showed above. I sample the text from the bitmap data and store it in a vector when then is used to create the texture with CreateTexture2D.

```
for (long y = 0; y < m_texture_height; y++)
{
    for (long x = 0; x < m_texture_width; x++)
    {
        BYTE alpha = (bitmap_bits[m_texture_width * y + x] & 0xff);

        if (alpha > 0)
            pixel_data.push_back(0xFFFFFF00 + alpha);
        else
            pixel_data.push_back(0);
    }
}
```

My back buffer uses DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, however I have tried DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM and experienced no change. If there's any other information I should provide please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

So in true programmer fashion, I solved the issue after being frustrated with it forever. BITMAPINFO stores in ARGB format, not RGBA like I was expected. The solution is just changing the alpha reading to this.

```
for (long y = 0; y < m_texture_height; y++)
{
    for (long x = 0; x < m_texture_width; x++)
    {
        BYTE alpha = (bitmap_bits[m_texture_width * y + x] & 0xff);

        if (alpha > 0)
            pixel_data.push_back((alpha << 24) | 0x00FFFFFF);
        else
            pixel_data.push_back(0);
    }
}
```